# Сортировка массива

Tags: c++

Как можно отсортировать элементы массива, находящиеся слева от найденной позиции KEY, по убыванию, а элементы массива, находящиеся справа от найденной позиции KEY, по возрастанию? Спасибо всем.

Answer (score 5):

Воспользовавшись функцией sort из stl два раза. В параметрах она принимает начало, конец сортируемого участка, и третьим не обязательным параметром функцию-правило по которому сравниваются два элемента.
Пример:

```
sort(some_array + KEY_POS + 1,some_array+size, less<double>() );
sort(some_array,some_array + KEY_POS, greater<double>() );
```

Для использования sort подключить "algorithm", less&greater - "functional".

Comment: интересное решение... вообще не знал про  less<double>() и greater<double>() к своему стыду. Вечером дома поиграюсь с этим и обязательно возьму на заметку :)

Comment: Только less там по дефолту. :)

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте разбить на два под массива и отсортировать каждый как нужно, после чего уже склеить их оба, либо один массив двумя циклами, первый цикл от 0 до key, а второй от key до конца, ну и соответственно менять критерий сортировки в каждом цикле.

Если же задача не учебная, то все делается при помощи STL

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

main(){
    int key = 3;
    int arr[] = {3,2,1,4,5,6};

    vector<int> sortedVector (arr, arr+6);
    vector<int>::iterator it;

    sort(sortedVector.begin(), sortedVector.begin() + key);
    sort(sortedVector.begin() + key, sortedVector.end(), greater<int>());

    for (it = sortedVector.begin(); it != sortedVector.end(); ++it)
        cout << " " << *it;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```